# How can I format the week as a 2 digit number even if it contains a 0 (01, 02 etc.)

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code I currently have:

```
txtWeek = Format(Date, "ww")
```

What code can I add so that when I print "txtweek" it shows up as two digits so for the current date as Week 01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format it once again.

```
Format(Format(Date, "ww"), "0#")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and easy solution!